# What is the device in the garden in the first episode?

Tags: kinos-journey

What is the device which the white shirted (unnamed) man was working on in his garden in episode 1?

In my opinion, it may be something for communicating with his wife, since they are not able to come close to each other. But I can't make sure of it.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The light novel doesn't give much context about the machine, and just describes it as a 小さな機械 (lit. small machine/apparatus).

One assume by the location ns accessories (hose) that it's for watering the garden. Since the inhabitants of this city are all hikikomori-types, it would make sense for machines to do all the work, life watering the plants.